# using if statements and icons in flutter

Tags: if-statement, dart, icons, flutter

i have an if statement and I want to set two conditions inside it as the following code shows:

```
if (subtitle !="you are currently not signed in" && Icon==Icons.bookmark_border) {.....}
```

but I cant do so since it is giving the following error "equality operator == invocation with reference of unrelated types".

Any idea about how to implement this

Comment: what is the value of "Icon" var ?

Comment: Use IconData instead of Icon. Also what is your variable here that you are trying to compare to Icons.bookmark_border?

Comment: i have future builder that returns 2 widgets ,one is bookmark and other is bookmark border icon, i want to set them into variables and put them into if statement.@VikasPandey

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the Code where you get your Icon that you want to compare?
Like @creativecreatorormaybenot already said you're trying to compare the Icon **type** with an object of type IconData, you need to compare an iconData **object** to another iconData **object**.

Note:
IconData is just the class for one of the icons in `Icons.[something]`
Icon is a flutter widget, used to display Icons for the user.

So

```
final IconData icon = Icons.ac_unit; //icon is just the name of the Object. IconData would be the type.

//replace icon with the object (of type IconData) you get from your FutureBuilder
if (subtitle !="you are currently not signed in" && icon==Icons.bookmark_border) {.....}
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.